# FLASH PLAYER won't upgrade

Tags: upgrade, flash

Adobe's page says it now has a secure flash player to upgrade to but I get the msg that Ubuntu won't support it.

HOW CAN I WATCH VIDEOS? Is there another player?

Comment: *"HOW CAN I WATCH VIDEOS? Is there another player?"* Yes HTML5 supports video playback natively in current browsers and the WebM format is the best solution currently for Linux users, websites just need to implement it.

Answer (score 1):

Ubuntu does support flash (using [`flashplugin-installer`](http://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/flashplugin-installer) from the repos)

You should be able to update/install it using:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer
```

or, it and other software should also be updated if you use:

```
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

The updated version is currently 11.2.202.491, which should fix the security issues and firefox blocking it.

Comment: This won't help until an update is released.

Comment: @ThomasW. The current version for Linux is 11.2.202.491, which the latest Firefox thinks is ok to allow to run (on 14.04 atleast). It does block the 481 version though.

Comment: That's mostly because an update was recently released yesterday.  Read [this](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/SecurityTeam/KnowledgeBase/FirefoxAndAdobeFlashNPAPI)